# Erro de Rotas no Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application

***Meu App.Vue***

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

</style>
```

***Meu Home.Vue component***

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

***Meu main.js***

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-route';
import Home from './components/home/Home.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);


var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Estou tendo esse erro , estou usando o vue-route

> TypeError: Vue.directive is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu pude ver o `import` do `VueRouter` está escrito errado, faltou um **r**

Deveria ser:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
```

Comment: Vlw, só agora percebi que além de estar escrito errado dei um `npm install` também com o nome errado.